# No default constructor - inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, extends

ok, so I have a class "Card" with the following constructor. suit and rank are stored as fields.

```
Card(String s, int r ){
    suit = s;
    rank = r;
}
```

I want to return the rank with this method

```
public int getRank(){
   return rank;
}
```

The thing is i want to call this method from another class named `Hand`
if I make a reference to the card class `Card c = new Card();` I have to input the parameters to the constructor. I don't want to do this.
I have tried to make `Hand` extend `Card`, but then I get the error

> no default constructor

I've searched for a solution but I just can't get it to work.
My question is: How do get around this problem?

Edit: Hand class

```
    public class Hand extends Card {
    Deck d = new Deck();
    Hand h = new Hand();
    ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<>();


    public void giveMeCard(){
        hand.add(d.dealCard());
    }


    public ArrayList returnHand(){
        return hand;
    }

public int rank(){


    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your `Hand` class.

Comment: If you want to call the Card constructor without any argument, then the Card class must have a constructor that doesn't take any argument. But what would a card without a suit or rank be useful for? Inheritance is completely irrelevant. A Hand is not a Card, so Hand should not extend Card. That makes no sense.

Comment: Yea please post the hand class

Comment: What card do you want `c` to hold when you've called `Card c = new Card()`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? I think you're lacking some fundamental java/programming knowledge so your best idea is probably to do some OO tutorials then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Why do you want Hand to inherit from Card? I would say instead that a Hand contains Cards, doesn't it? (in Java, Hand would have a List of type Card)

Comment: Note that your Hand class doesn't make much sense either. In your design, A Hand has another Hand (which thus has another Hand, which has another Hand...). So constructing a Hand will throw a StackOverflowError. A Hand doesn't have any rank. It has several cards, which all have a different rank. You migh ask the Hand what the minimum or maximum rank of its cards is, for example, but asking its rank doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 3):

> I have to input the parameters to the constructor. I don't want to do this.

The solution to your problem is to start *wanting* to do this.

A `Card` without a specific suit and rank is meaningless.  You do not want to be instantiating meaningless objects.

You have not told us what your reasons are for not wanting to instantiate your card with the parameters that its constructor expects, but whatever your reasons are, they cannot possibly win over correctness.

So, you should pass the suit and rank to the constructor, you should do whatever it takes to be able to pass them, and you should not only want to do this, but actually love doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I class has no parameterless constructor, then subclasses must call one of existing constructors of base class.

In your case you have base class

```
class Card {
  Card(String s, int r ){
}
```

so you must have

```
Hand extend Card {
 Hand() {
  super("s","r");
}
```

That's about technical side. About modeling and logic side, **it makes absolutely no sense that `Hand` extends `Card`. `Hand` is not a `Card`**. It contains `set of cards` (probably empty set=no cards in hand). Also (probably) there is upper limit of cards in hand (depends on the game you model).

Your card model is correct. It must have suit and rank (those fields should be private final in `Card` class). Your card should be immutable. Players should not be able to alter card in hand to some other cards, right? Actually I would model `Rank` and `Suit` as enums (they have well-known, limited set of values).
In any case (rank/suit as string or enum) you need `equals/hashcode` in `Card` and `Hand` classes.

You may event want to model `Cards` as enums, or as `final static` fields in `Card` class (one instance for actual cards).

When dealing a `card`, you must know what card to deal: rank and suit of that card. I guess, you are not dealing joker cards, where player can paint whatever he wants to on the card?

For me, you should also have `Deck` card. `giveMeCard` method should take (random) card from `Deck`, remove it from deck and add to Hand. Probably `deal` is better name of the method. It better reflects underlying domain (card game).

Comment: You may want to rethink your `super("s","r")` example.